# How to click "a" tag without href, to load more comments before scraping all comments - Web Scraping (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to click a div that contains `a` tag without `href` to view more comments but it doesn't be clicked.

[image: Check this attached Screenshot for the HTML script]

Code Snipest:

```
def TEST(self):
    URL = "https://www.dr.com/audoctors/dr-Jourge.htm"
    CONTENT = self.GET_SOUP_OUTPUT(URL)
    BASE = CONTENT.findAll("div", {"class":"d5_review"})
    print(len(BASE))
    LINK = CONTENT.find("/html/body/div[1]/section[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[6]/a")
    while True:
        if LINK:
            LINK.click()
        else: 
            break
    BASE = CONTENT.findAll("div", {"class":"d5_review"})
    print(len(BASE))
    return BASE
```

Spec:
Python:3.7
Selenuim: 3.141.0
Beautifulsoup: 4.8.2

Does anyone help, please?

Comment: How are you getting the `GET_SOUP_OUTPUT()` ?? using selenium or python request module? if is selenium then click on review link element using selenium webdriver.

Comment: you cannot click with a soup tag.